# stringWithContentsOfFile only works for NSUTF16StringEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Im trying to read a .csv file in iOS, when I use NSUTF8StringEncoding, it prints null - when I use NSUTF16StringEncoding, it prints my file as chinese characters.. Can anyone inform me as to whats going on here? I have dragged my .csv into the main project directory, and coppied files. Here is my sample code:

```
 NSError *error;
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Crane_Data" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"TEST");
NSLog(@"%@",fileData);
NSLog(@"TEST");
```

After error test using:

```
 if (!fileData) NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

I got this with NSUTF8

```
2014-06-20 22:20:57.351 CollectionView[6084:390557] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0xaf5a7b0 {NSFilePath=/Users/Dylan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D3F54177-0F08-47A5-9FE0-785E2AF0691A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/81942FA8-BB67-4E8D-826E-7D1A445DD9B0/CollectionView.app/Crane_Data.csv, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

And no error printed on the console using NSUTF16

Comment: Try this `if (!fileData) NSLog(@"%@", error);` and let us know what the error message is.

Comment: I attempted this and posted the result above. Not sure if I have to comment for you to be notified

Comment: Appears to be simple ASCII, which should work with UTF8. Can you post the end of the file? (Just the last couple lines from the debug output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is plane ASCII:

I took the bytes from the comments and formatted them for a char string, then created a NSString:

```
char* bytes = "\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x69\x64\x2c\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x61\x63\x74\x2c\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x74\x79\x70\x65\x2c\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x72\x6f\x6f\x74\x2c\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x2c\x66\x6f\x72\x74\x75\x6e\x65\x5f\x64\x65\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x0d\x31\x2c\x31\x2c\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2c\x70\x2c\x4d\x61\x6b\x65\x20\x61\x6e\x20\x6f\x72\x69\x67\x61\x6d\x69\x20\x63\x72\x61\x6e\x65\x20\x2c\x0d\x32\x2c\x31\x2c\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2c\x70\x2c\x57\x72\x69\x74\x65\x20\x6f\x6e\x65\x20\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x20\x6f\x66\x20\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x67\x2e\x2c\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x63\x6f\x6d\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\x63\x68\x61\x6c\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x65\x20\x69\x73\x20\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x6e\x64\x65\x64\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x62\x65\x20\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x69\x76\x65\x2e\x20\x49\x74\x20\x63\x61\x6e\x6e\x6f\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x6c\x00";
NSUInteger bytesLength = strlen(bytes);
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:bytesLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

NSLog Output:

> string:
>   fortune_id,fortune_act,fortune_type,fortune_root,fortune_string,fortune_description
>           1,1,composition,p,Make an origami crane ,
>           2,1,composition,p,Write one line of something.,This composition challenge is intended to be creative. It cannot be a l

Below is the initial response:
If it is utf-16 there are three possibilities:
`NSUTF16StringEncoding`
`NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding`
`NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding.`
Try all three.

If that fails get the data:
`NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`
Then log it:
`NSLog(@"fileData: %@", fileData);`
Post the first hundred bytes of so. It should be easy to figure out the format.
Also post what it should be if you have that information.

Comment: 666f7274 756e655f 69642c66 6f727475 6e655f61 63742c66 6f727475 6e655f74 7970652c 666f7274 756e655f 726f6f74 2c666f72 74756e65 5f737472 696e672c 666f7274 756e655f 64657363 72697074 696f6e0d 312c312c 636f6d70 6f736974 696f6e2c 702c4d61 6b652061 6e206f72 6967616d 69206372 616e6520 2c0d322c 312c636f 6d706f73 6974696f 6e2c702c 57726974 65206f6e 65206c69 6e65206f 6620736f 6d657468 696e672e 2c546869 7320636f 6d706f73 6974696f 6e206368 616c6c65 6e676520 69732069 6e74656e 64656420 746f2062 65206372 65617469 76652e20 49742063 616e6e6f 74206265 2061206c  
 --- All 3 encodings seem to do the same thing

Comment: ORIGINAL:
fortune_id,fortune_act,fortune_type,fortune_root,fortune_string,fortune_description
1,1,composition,p,Make an origami crane ,
2,1,composition,p,Write one line of something.,This composition challenge is intended to be creative. It cannot be a line for school or work. Ideally you will write one line of the same thing every day but this is up to you.
3,0,obscure,v,Place some sum of money in a sealed jar. ,It is a sum of your choosing. You must place money in the same sealed jar every time you complete this challenge. You or someone else may not remove the money.

Comment: It looks like ASCII: `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` is a little more forgiving in that it an 8-bit ASCII+ encoding.

Comment: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding appears to be the solution! Thank you!